Android Macrobenchmark 1.2.4: StartupMode.COLD breaks the benchmarks. Inside measure block UiAutomator can't find any objects
I have added macrobenchmark module with StartupTimingMetric and FrameTimingMetric metrics long time ago and my setup was working fine. Since then I have not been running benchmarks due to some reasons. Recently, had time to go back and update the user flows and run the benchmarks again. But my FrameTimingMetric benchmarks started to fail at step of running measureBlock. UiAutomator couldn't find any object by resource id inside of measureBlock but could see all of them in setupBlock. I'm using Compose and necessary composables have testTag added.
It was working fine a year ago when I have added benchmarks initially, but now they stopped. In the end I managed to fix the problem by removing startupMode = StartupMode.COLD. I have no idea why this flag is affecting the visibility of composables in measureBlock only, while setupBlock works just fine.
Could someone help me understand why this is happening?
// NOT working case

        rule.measureRepeated(
            packageName = InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments().getString("targetAppId")
                ?: throw Exception("targetAppId not passed as instrumentation runner arg"),
            metrics = listOf(FrameTimingMetric()),
            compilationMode = compilationMode,
            startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
            iterations = 10,
            setupBlock = {
                pressHome()
                startActivityAndWait()
                // other setup methods
                // "MyList" is visible here and list var is NOT null
                // val list = device.findObject(By.res("MyList"))
            },
            measureBlock = {
                // "MyList" is NOT visible here and list var IS null
                val list = device.findObject(By.res("MyList"))
            }
        )

// Working case

        rule.measureRepeated(
            packageName = InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments().getString("targetAppId")
                ?: throw Exception("targetAppId not passed as instrumentation runner arg"),
            metrics = listOf(FrameTimingMetric()),
            compilationMode = compilationMode,
            // startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,      // <- REMOVE this line
            iterations = 10,
            setupBlock = {
                pressHome()
                startActivityAndWait()
                // other setup methods
                // "MyList" is visible here and list var is NOT null
                // val list = device.findObject(By.res("MyList"))
            },
            measureBlock = {
                // "MyList" is visible here and list var is NOT null
                val list = device.findObject(By.res("MyList"))
            }
        )


If StartupMode.COLD is used, the app process is killed between the
execution of setupBlock and measureBlock to allow for app preparation
without starting the process.
If you need the process to remain active, use
StartupMode.WARM, which restarts activities without restarting the process, or
set startupMode to null and call killProcess() within the setupBlock.
You can subscribe to b/278214396 to get more updates about this in the future.

Thank you @mlykotom for your help. It's so cool to receive an answer from you, the person whose videos and codelabs I was following to learn about macrobenchmark.  StartupMode.WARM did indeed work out

Honestly it is surprising to see the change in the behaviour of FrameTimeMetrics + StartupMode.COLD. The Inspecting Performance - MAD Skills videos still show that StartupMode.COLD can be used with FrameTimeMetrics. After watching the mad skills videos and going through the codelab, I came to an impression that app process is the same from the start of the iteration until the end. So setupBlock and measure block are both part of single process. They are there only to separate what to measure and what to skip in measurements.

Therefore, it seems unintuitive that startupMode.COLD would control process state between setup and measure blocks. Expected behaviour for FrameTimeMetrics + StartupMode.COLD would be complete killing of the process and cold start of the app between iterations. The fact that UIAutomator doesn't see any ui elements in measure block seems to be a bug, rather than expected behaviour.

startupMode to null and call killProcess() within the setupBlock is the closet configuration that would bring back the behaviour described in the MAD skills video and the code lab. So thank you for giving this hint and for opening the https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278214396. I couldn't agree more with the issues you have raised there with current behaviour of the library

Do you think the two solutions you have provided are temporary or more like permanent? Since the issue ticket was reopened and accepted, should we expect the change in the behaviour of the startupMode configurations?

The behavior will most likely stay the same so that there's a possibilty for COLD startup to prepare the app process somehow, which wouldn't be possible otherwise, because when you interact with a process in any way (send a broadcast for example), the proces is awaken and hence wouldn't be COLD.
It's possible that the API for startup modes might slightly change, but it's too soon to speculate and hence I would recommend using the current approach :)
